# What is the right ABP template for create a new microservice?

Tags: abp

I have created a new solution with the ABP CLI using the Microservice Template.
What is the right template for create a new single microservice (like ProductService)?

If the template doesn't exists what is the suggested and faster way to have a working microservice in Abp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABP Commercial users can use the `microservice-service-pro` template to add a new microservice to their microservice solution.

**Example command**:

```sh
abp new ProductService -t microservice-service-pro
```

You can read the [Add new Microservices to the Solution](https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/latest/startup-templates/microservice/add-microservice) documentation to see how to add a new service to your solution and make the related configurations.